# Modifying `babel-register server.js` after updating `babel-register` to `@babel/register`

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, babel-register

I am updating the babel packages used in [a boilerplate](https://github.com/epilande/yarems/blob/master/package.json#L9), from `babel-core`, `babel-register`, etc., to `@babel/core`, `@babel/register`, etc.

**Problem:** In the npm script `dev`, it was previously using `babel-register` to run `server.js`.

```
"dev": "concurrently -k 'node -r babel-register server.js' 'npm start'",
```

After updating the `babel-register` npm package to `@babel/register`, the above script throws the error

> Error: Cannot find module 'babel-register'

What is the correct command to update `babel-register server.js`?

Comment: Isn't `babel-register` a require hook and `babel-node` is usual approach to transpile file via command. `babel-node server.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same as the other places. You'd want

```
node -r @babel/register server.js
```

Comment: Encountered the error `As of v7.0.0-beta.55, we've removed Babel's Stage presets...`. Performed `npx babel-upgrade --save --write`. `npm run dev` now gives a new error `Error: Cannot find module '@babel/preset-stage-0'`. Should I install `@babel/preset-stage-0`?

Comment: As the error says, the stage presets no longer exists. You should install the specific experimental plugins that you want to use.